# Angular component comuniaction

Tags: javascript, html, angular, web, components

I need help about angular component comunication.

I have Parent component and children.

In parent component i have list. I would like to click of item list and move data {name, text} to children component and set it to children component where is froala editor.

Comment: Start here: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Comment: This is overly broad. Please be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

In Angular, there are two ways you can do implement component intercommunication.

1. Pass data from parent to child with input binding

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-parent',
  template: `
    <app-child [childMessage]="parentMessage"></app-child>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./parent.component.css']
})
export class ParentComponent{
  parentMessage = "message from parent"
  constructor() { }
}
```

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  template: `
      Say {{ message }}
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./child.component.css']
})

export class ChildComponent {

  @Input() childMessage: string;

  constructor() { }

}
```

2. Using Angular Services(This method is used when the components communicating are directly related ). But from you are describing you can do it better with angular service. When you click the item list, you can call the function of services that pushes the data to the BehaviourSubject. After that, all the component that are subscribed to that Behaviour subject will get the data you passed.

```
@Injectable()
export class DataService {

  private messageSource = new BehaviorSubject('default message');
  currentMessage = this.messageSource.asObservable();

  constructor() { }

  changeMessage(message: string) {
    this.messageSource.next(message)
  }

}
```

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from "../data.service";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-parent',
  template: `
    {{message}}
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./sibling.component.css']
})
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {

  message:string;

  constructor(private data: DataService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.data.currentMessage.subscribe(message => this.message = message)
  }

}
```

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from "../data.service";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-sibling',
  template: `
    {{message}}
    <button (click)="newMessage()">New Message</button>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./sibling.component.css']
})
export class SiblingComponent implements OnInit {

  message:string;

  constructor(private data: DataService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.data.currentMessage.subscribe(message => this.message = message)
  }

  newMessage() {
    this.data.changeMessage("Hello from Sibling")
  }

}
```